# Issue with delaying CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to delay a CSS transition, but it seems not to be working. Here is what I want to happen:

1. Start the video
2. Move the mouse pointer out of the video
3. The control bar shrinks, but the play-progress gets larger.
4. Move mouse pointer back in video, the control bar returns to normal.

As you can see in the CodePen pen, the play-progress bar gets larger before I want it to: http://codepen.io/mboles/pen/mJeJOO

Here is the CSS I am currently using:

```
#myPlayerID.vjs-has-started.vjs-user-inactive .vjs-progress-control {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px);
}

#myPlayerID.vjs-has-started.vjs-user-inactive .vjs-play-progress {
  -transition-delay: height 3s; 
  height: 10px;
}
```

I have tried to change the order of the transition delay and height, but that did not solve the issue.

Many thanks-
Matt

Answer (score 0):

It turns out with transition-delay you cannot put the property with the delay, it must be explicitly stated using transition-property. So the solution is:

```
#myPlayerID.vjs-has-started.vjs-user-inactive .vjs-play-progress {
  height: 10px;
  transition-property: height;
  -transition-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 3s; 
}
```